# How to use firebase angularjs authentication to store user data in laravel's database

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-4, firebase, firebasesimplelogin

I'm using laravel 4.2 + angularjs + firebase + firebase simple login.

And i want my users to login thought the firebase simple login and store the user's data like name email  access_token in my laravel user's database.

I know how to authenticate the users thought firebase simple login but the problem is how to store those  login data ...

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that you already have. Then highlight in that code where you are stuck.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve